# How to delete data older than particular month specified in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-delete

I want to delete data for older than September month of this year. Previously i was trying to delete data for older than 24 hours for which query is mentioned below and its working fine. The `TIMESTAMP` column has data type `date`.

```
Delete FROM ALERT_LOGS WHERE TIMESTAMP > SYSDATE - 1 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Delete FROM ALERT_LOGS WHERE TIMESTAMP < DATE '2015-09-01' ;
```